# Is it possible to use JavaScript instead of Dart on Flutter to make cross platform mobile apps?

Tags: javascript, flutter, mobile-application

Is it possible to use JavaScript instead of Dart on Flutter to make cross platform mobile apps ?

Comment: No. I think that's the point.

Comment: It looks like flutter has some sort of web support, their docs hint at exporting your Dart code for use in web: https://flutter.dev/web - However, remember that the point of Flutter is to develop applications for mobile, web, and desktop from a single codebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Flutter won't "compile" JS code, it is possible to use platform native code however (Swift, Obj-C, Java, Kotlin) to specific tasks.

Even if you want to use Flutter to create a web application, you need to write it in Dart.

Comment: there are  some attempts though, but I wouldn't recommend for production purposes... https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can:
https://github.com/openkraken/kraken
I think this project is from Alibaba, and with it you can use js instead of dart, and then it will be rendered by flutter.